# Reduce network call

Tags: angular, http

I have 2 components UsersComponent and HelloComponent.

I am calling the same service with the same api calls on both the component.

But I want is that if UsersComponent is calling the api than HelloComponent should not call the api it should recieve the value from UsersComponent.

Currently network call is happening on both of the component.

Is there any way to do.Please help.

Stackblitz link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-service-3ifvpr?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts

Really appreciate if you put working demo inside stackblitz.

Comment: What version of Angular are you working in? Your stackblitz is v4

Comment: Currently in the project I am using v7 but in stackblitz in v4

Comment: I would recommend providing a stackblitz in the correct version if you want someone to provide a modified version. Answers are likely to involve RxJS, which has changed between Angular versions 4 and 7.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a home made cache in your service like this maybe and use your service in both component (think it's best pratice)

```
// Map of your posts <idPost, Post>
private posts: Map<number, any>;

getPosts(): Observable<any[]> {

    let data: Observable<any[]>;

    if (this.posts) {
      data = defer(() => Promise.resolve(Array.from(this.posts.values())));
    } else {
      data = this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').pipe(
        map(results => {
          this.posts= new Map();
          results.forEach(post => {
            this.posts.set(post.id, post);
          });
          return results;
        })
      );
    }

    return data ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a simple solution you can create a [Resolver](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) which will load and cache the data. Resolver loads data before the component is created, so you will have all the data loaded in the component constructor. Here is an example of a resolver:

```js
// data.resolver.ts

export interface DataResolverData {
  data: any;
  error?: Error;
}

@Injectable()
export class DataResolver implements Resolve<DataResolverData> {
  private data?: any;

  constructor(
    private readonly appService: AppService
  ) {}

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot
  ): Observable<DataResolverData> {
    if (this.data) {
      return of({
        data: this.data
      });
    } else {
      return this.appService.getData().pipe(
        catchError(err => of({
          error: err
        })),
        tap(response => {
          this.data = response;
        }),
        map(response => ({
          data: response
        }))
      );
    }
  }
}
```

```js
// app.module.ts

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  // note that I've added the same resolver for both routes
  { path: 'hello', component: HelloComponent, resolve: {data: DataResolver} },
  { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent, resolve: {data: DataResolver} }
];

...

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers:    [ AppService, DataResolver ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```js
// hello.component.ts

export class HelloComponent  {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    const { data, error } = this.route.snapshot.data.data as DataResolverData;
    console.log('hello', data, error);
  }
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-service-yf8cd5)

Actually you can store and cache data in a service which will be reused by multiple resolvers or components. It depends on the app context and requirements.

Another solution might be to use a store like [NgRx](https://ngrx.io/guide/store) or [NGXS](https://www.ngxs.io/). A store it's a much more involved solution, and isn't suitable for every project, here is a [good article](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-redux-ngrx-rxjs/) about pros and cons of using a store solution in an angular app. I just mentioned it because it's relevant to the problem.